# Laravel Passport v11 no longer redirects to authorization form

Tags: laravel-passport

I upgraded to Laravel Passport v11 and now when I request authorization I no longer get redirected back to the authorize form after login. This is my code below:

```
$query = http_build_query([
  'client_id' => '6',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/oauth2_client/callback.php',
  'response_type' => 'code',
  'scope' => '',
]);

header('Location: http://127.0.0.1:8000/recruiter/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
```

In version 10 all of this was working. After successful login it should present the authorize form. Scoured the docs and GitHub but not much to go off.

Comment: Do you have a server with a remote debugger, so you can compare the behaviour difference between v10 and v11? I expect this cannot be debugged locally because of the OAuth requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve by ensuring I added the relevant guard inside `passport.config` file.

Also if you move the passport routes to `routes/web.php` file then remember to add the `oauth/token` route to your `VerifyCSRFToken` middlewares `$except` array. This one threw me as it will return null otherwise. The Laravel passport documentation is lacking this information.

Comment: Is it worth raising a bug in the Laravel documentation project to cover the issue you mention?